# ImportError: cannot import name 'modname_tkinter' from 'PyInstaller.compat'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

PyInstaller: 5.0.1 
Python: 3.7.9 
Output: https://gist.github.com/phonebotco/eee157bd12a3b9f0792b2fcab9478636

I am trying to compile my code with this command:

`pyinstaller --onefile -F --uac-admin --icon="favicon_phonebot.ico" --exclude-module modname_tkinter --debug=all PhoneBot.py`

I get this error message:

```
  File "c:\users\gauth\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks\hook-IPython.py", line 16, in <module>
    from PyInstaller.compat import modname_tkinter, is_win, is_darwin
ImportError: cannot import name 'modname_tkinter' from 'PyInstaller.compat' (c:\users\gauth\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\gauth\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\gauth\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\gauth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\gauth\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 178, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\gauth\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 59, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\gauth\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 845, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "c:\users\gauth\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 767, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "H:\Mon Drive\Phonebot\Phonebot_debug3\PhoneBot.spec", line 20, in <module>
    noarchive=False,
  File "c:\users\gauth\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 319, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\gauth\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 173, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\gauth\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 487, in assemble
    self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks(self)
  File "c:\users\gauth\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 326, in process_post_graph_hooks
    module_hook.post_graph(analysis)
  File "c:\users\gauth\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 398, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "c:\users\gauth\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 364, in _load_hook_module
    raise ImportErrorWhenRunningHook(self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
PyInstaller.exceptions.ImportErrorWhenRunningHook: Failed to import module __PyInstaller_hooks_0_IPython required by hook for module c:\users\gauth\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks\hook-IPython.py. Please check whether module __PyInstaller_hooks_0_IPython actually exists and whether the hook is compatible with your version of c:\users\gauth\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks\hook-IPython.py: You might want to read more about hooks in the manual and provide a pull-request to improve PyInstaller.

H:\Mon Drive\Phonebot\Phonebot_debug3>pyinstaller --onefile -F --uac-admin --icon="favicon_phonebot.ico" --exclude-module modname_tkinter --debug=all PhoneBot.py
```

The weird thing is I don't use [Tkinter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tkinter) in my code. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip install -U pyinstaller-hooks-contrib
```

I was using an outdated version of **pyinstaller-hooks-contrib**. The offending import line in that IPython hook was removed over a year ago.

Comment: installing the new version of hooks did not work for me; is there a workaround? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was using Pyinstaller version 5.1 and had similar error. After I downgraded Pyinstaller to version 4.5.1 the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it helped update the Kivy library to the lastest version.

Comment: For me also upgrading Kivy from 2.0.0 to 2.1.0 solved issue with PyInstaller.
python -m pip install --upgrade kivy[full] kivy_examples