# Pyinstaller raise a warning when I run it

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

Hi when I try to convert my kivy python application to an executable file , it gives me the following error , any ideas on how to fix it ?

```
 PyInstaller.exceptions.ImportErrorWhenRunningHook: Failed to import module __PyInstaller_hooks_0_kivy required by hook for module /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-kivy.py. Please check whether module __PyInstaller_hooks_0_kivy actually exists and whether the hook is compatible with your version of /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-kivy.py: You might want to read more about hooks in the manual and provide a pull-request to improve PyInstaller.
761086 WARNING: stderr: PyInstaller.exceptions.ImportErrorWhenRunningHook: Failed to import module __PyInstaller_hooks_0_kivy required by hook for module /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-kivy.py. Please check whether module __PyInstaller_hooks_0_kivy actually exists and whether the hook is compatible with your version of /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-kivy.py: You might want to read more about hooks in the manual and provide a pull-request to improve PyInstaller.
```

Comment: What version of PyInstaller are you running ? You could try generate the kivy hook yourself with this command `python -m kivy.tools.packaging.pyinstaller_hooks hook kivy-hook.py` and add the generated hook to your pyinstaller command line.

Comment: The PyInstaller version is 5.1and I have tried that command but its says that  'No module named kivy.tools.packaging' and also i get thie error too : 'pyinstaller: error: the following arguments are required: scriptname'

Comment: I was having the same issue that I solved by downgrading pyinstaller to 4.5.1 as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72272392/importerror-cannot-import-name-modname-tkinter-from-pyinstaller-compat

Answer (score 0):

pip install -U pyinstaller-hooks-contrib

Answer (score 0):

The 'enum34' package is an obsolete backport of a standard library package and is incompatible with PyInstaller. Please remove this package
run : python.exe" -m pip uninstall enum34

Comment: Explain what you are installing, mention versions of what you are installing. Which python is installed? Did you remove the package with command line the error message included?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).